# FullCalendar com comportamento estranho ao exibir eventos no "Month View" que terminam antes das 9 horas

Tags: fullcalendar

O FullCalendar tem um comportamento padrão para exibição no *month view* que ignora os finais de eventos quando terminam antes das 9am, exemplo:

**Week view:** (terminando antes das 9am do dia 4)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é mostrado no **Month view**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Week view:** (terminando depois das 9am do dia 4)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é mostrado no **Month view**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como corrigir isso? Gostaria que o evento fosse mostrado no dia 3 e 4 mesmo que termine antes das 9 horas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para alterar essa comportamento padrão é necessário alterar a propriedade *nextDayThreshold*, responsável por definir as horas mínimas para ser considerado um dia de evento no month view. Ele tem como padrão *"09:00:00" (9am)* de acordo com a documentação:

> When an event's end time spans into another day, the minimum time it
>   must be in order for it to render as if it were on that day.
>
> Duration, default: "09:00:00" (9am)

Mais informações em http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/